# Sweet and Sour?

Tags: flavor, food-science, sugar, acidity

In comments related to [this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/66776/what-are-the-key-differences-between-lemons-and-meyer-lemons), there was discussion about pH, fructose concentration, what compounds a fruit contains, etc. influencing or determining "flavor".

Much more recently, I had a couple kiwifruits, which seemed to have a very sweet *flavor* but left me with the feeling of a mild acid burn on my tongue and lips, similar to the feeling of eating too much fresh pineapple.  Both of those fruits are listed as Acid fruits [here](http://www.imraw.me/fruit-list-acid-sub-acid-sweet.html), along with strawberries (which have a flavor experience of being sweet and not acidic).

[This question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/28673/ph-and-sour-acid-taste) indicates that the perception of acids in food is more a function of how many anions are in a food (as a % of total molecules), not the pH.  At the same time, pH may be important for certain chemical processes in food preparation.

[This question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/83361/go-figure-are-they-infinitives), among other sources, frames sweetness and sourness as opposites, and strange (but common) to put together in a dish - yet these two seem to be together naturally in some fruits (e.g. kiwi & pineapple as discussed above).  [This question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/17395/why-does-adding-sugar-to-sour-things-cause-them-not-to-be-sour) suggests that sugar masks perception of sourness (but not acidity) and [this one](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/24733/is-it-incorrect-when-someones-says-you-can-lower-acidity-with-sweetness) suggests sweetness actually reduces sourness (but not acidity), rather than just masking it.

**Is there any connection, linkage, or correlation (even if negative) between sweetness and sourness, ideally based on an understanding of what attributes in a food underly these?  Are they independent of one another?**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36564/discussion-between-jefromi-and-wbt).

Comment: I\m thinking the two are independent. Think lemons. Very sour, yet high in sugar, which is sweet.